# I'm looking for a better way to write this query using only ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Trying to rewrite this code more ActiveRecord only.

```
.where("external_id in(select external_id from bmp group by external_id having count(*) > 1)")
```

Comment: Bmp.group(:external_id).having('count(*) >1').select(:id) . Can you try this

Comment: Why not just use a INNER JOIN? What are the models, tables and expected result?

Comment: `.where(external_id: Bmp.select(:external_id).group(:external_id).having(Arel.star.count.gt(1)))` should result in this exact condition (Assuming `Bmp` is a "model"). Whether or not that is correct for your use case is really up to you.

Comment: Thank you, guys! @engineersmnky, your answer fits perfectly!